# How can I merge structures/structure arrays in MATLAB?

Tags: arrays, matlab, merge, concatenation, matlab-struct

I am trying to merge two structs with identical fields. I tried several ways, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5882177/matlab-structure-merge) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38645/what-are-some-efficient-ways-to-combine-two-structures-in-matlab). But it either turns out sideways or doesn't work at all.

My two (simplified) structs are

```
a(1).name = 'x';
a(1).data = 1;
a(2).name = 'y';
a(2).data = 2;
```

and

```
b(1).name = 'x';
b(1).data = 3;
b(2).name = 'y';
b(2).data = 4;
```

The desired output is identical to what this would produce:

```
c(1).name = 'x';
c(1).data = 1;
c(2).name = 'y';
c(2).data = 2;
c(3).name = 'x';
c(3).data = 3;
c(4).name = 'y';
c(4).data = 4;
```

What is an easy way to do this? In my real struct, there are more than two fields with over a thousand values.

Comment: ```c = [a b]```

Comment: @MatthiasW. No way *facepalm*

Comment: ah..I was just about to suggest `horzcat` - or [a b] as @MatthiasW. suggested.

Comment: In the general case where you do not have exactly matching fields, you may want to check out  http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7842-catstruct

Answer (score 1):

The following does that.

```
%-------------------------------------------------------
a(1).name = 'x';
a(1).data = 1;
a(2).name = 'y';
a(2).data = 2;
b(1).name = 'x';
b(1).data = 3;
b(2).name = 'y';
b(2).data = 4;

c = struct('name',{a(:).name,b(:).name},'data',{a(:).data,b(:).data});
%-------------------------------------------------------
>> c(1)
ans =
    name: 'x'
    data: 1
>> c(2)
ans =
    name: 'y'
    data: 2
>> c(3)
ans =
    name: 'x'
    data: 3
>> c(4)
ans =
    name: 'y'
    data: 4
```

Answer (score 1):

This was answered tersely in [a comment by Matthias W.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35035716/matlab-merging-structs/42959311#comment57796188_35035716), so I'll elaborate here...

When [structures](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/structures.html) have identical fields, you can treat them just as any other object when [concatenating](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/creating-and-concatenating-matrices.html) them. The solution for the above example would be:

```
c = [a b];
```

Since `a` and `b` in this case are 1-by-2 structure arrays, this [horizontally concatenates](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/horzcat.html) them into a larger 1-by-4 structure array. If the sizes/dimensions of `a` and `b` weren't known, we could do this:

```
c = [a(:).' b(:).'];
```

This uses the [colon operator](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html) to reshape them into column arrays, then [transposes](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/transpose.html) them into row arrays before concatenating them.

### More complicated cases...

- **Merge fields across structures:** [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5882177/52738) deals with the case when you want to combine multiple structures (with the same fields) into a *single* structure (not a structure array). In this case, *each individual field* is being concatenated across a number of structures.
- **Merge different structures into one:** [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38645/52738) deals with the case where you have multiple structures with *different* fields and you want to merge them into one single structure with *all* the fields from each individual structure. The caveat that has to be considered here is how to handle collisions: if the same field appears in multiple structures, which field value appears in the final merged structure?